# Select() not poping up in DbSet<Category> Property

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This is first time I am trying EF core. I create separate class library for EF core created dbcontext `EXPENSEDBContext` class form the existing database and build successfully.

While I tried to select a record through the object of `EXPENSEDBContext` I could not able to see the `Select()` and `Where()`  as below

```
var selectvalues = db.Category.Select();
```

So as an alternate I used foreach instead of `Select()` as below

```
using (var db = new EXPENSEDBContext())
        {
            //
            var selectvalues = db.Category;

             foreach(var b in selectvalues)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(b.Name);
            }
        }
```

My question is why `Select` method is not poping up in `db.Category`.

Comment: How do you define Category property on your DbContext? Show us the code

Comment: public virtual DbSet<Catagory> Catagory { get; set; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you correctly defined `Category` property as you said in your comment

```
public virtual DbSet<Catagory> Catagory { get; set; }
```

so make sure you added the following using statement:

```
using System.Linq;
```

If it doesn't compile so make sure to install the [System.Linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq/) nuget package:

```
Install-Package System.Linq
```